# list index out of range when popping elements after for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

```
def main():
    hash_table = [
        [75],
        [95, 64],
        [17, 47, 82],
        [18, 35, 87, 10],
        [20, 82, 47, 65],
        [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34],
        [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67],
        [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92],
        [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33],
        [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29],
        [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14],
        [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57],
        [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48],
        [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31],
        [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]
    ]
    while(len(hash_table)!=1):
        for i in range(len(hash_table[-2])):
            hash_table[-2][i]=hash_table[-2][i]+max(hash_table[-1][i],hash_table[-1][i+1])
        hash_table.pop(-1)
        print(hash_table)


main()
```

This is euler problem 18. It is running okay until this line comes out in the console:

```
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [686, 718, 731, 749]]
```

After this line it stops and throws the error.
This is the whole output from the console:

```
C:\Python3.85\python.exe C:/python_projects/algorithms/euler(18).py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python_projects/algorithms/euler(18).py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/python_projects/algorithms/euler(18).py", line 21, in main
    hash_table[-2][i]=hash_table[-2][i]+max(hash_table[-1][i],hash_table[-1][i+1])
IndexError: list index out of range
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92], [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33], [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29], [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14], [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57], [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48], [125, 164, 102, 95, 112, 123, 165, 128, 166, 109, 122, 147, 100, 54]]
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92], [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33], [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29], [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14], [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57], [255, 235, 154, 150, 140, 179, 256, 209, 224, 172, 174, 176, 148]]
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92], [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33], [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29], [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14], [325, 246, 187, 178, 256, 329, 273, 302, 263, 242, 193, 233]]
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92], [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33], [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29], [378, 317, 231, 321, 354, 372, 393, 354, 360, 293, 247]]
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92], [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33], [419, 365, 393, 387, 419, 425, 430, 376, 454, 322]]
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92], [460, 434, 419, 475, 508, 470, 510, 524, 487]]
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [559, 499, 479, 536, 514, 526, 594, 616]]
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [647, 501, 613, 609, 533, 657, 683]]
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 82, 47, 65], [666, 614, 636, 684, 660, 717]]
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [686, 718, 731, 749]]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Seems to be associated with the fact that the 5th sublist has only 4 elements.

Comment: You appear to be referring to https://projecteuler.net/problem=18 and if I change that line of your input to match what is there, i.e. `[20, 4, 82, 47, 65],`, then the problem goes away. I am going to vote to close this question as caused by a typo.